# How to use Rust shiplift from a hyper server

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I'm trying to write a simple Rust program that reads Docker stats using [shiplift](https://github.com/softprops/shiplift) and exposes them as Prometheus metrics using [rust-prometheus](https://github.com/pingcap/rust-prometheus).

The `shiplift` stats example runs correctly on its own, and I'm trying to integrate it in the server as

```
fn handle(_req: Request<Body>) -> Response<Body> {
    let docker = Docker::new();
    let containers = docker.containers();
    let id = "my-id";
    let stats = containers
        .get(&id)
        .stats().take(1).wait();
    for s in stats {
        println!("{:?}", s);
    }
    // ...
}

// in main
let make_service = || {
    service_fn_ok(handle)
};

let server = Server::bind(&addr)
    .serve(make_service);
```

but it appears that the stream hangs forever (I cannot produce any error message).

I've also tried the same refactor (using `take` and `wait` instead of `tokio::run`) in the [shiplift example](https://github.com/softprops/shiplift/blob/master/examples/stats.rs), but in that case I get the error `executor failed to spawn task: tokio::spawn failed (is a tokio runtime running this future?)`. Is `tokio` somehow required by `shiplift`?

EDIT:
If I've understood correctly, my attempt does not work because `wait` will block `tokio` executor and `stats` will never produce results.

Answer (score 0):

`shiplift`'s API is asynchronous, meaning `wait()` and other functions return a `Future`, instead of blocking the main thread until a result is ready. A `Future` won't actually do any I/O until it is passed to an executor. You need to pass the `Future` to `tokio::run` as in the example you linked to. You should read the [tokio docs](https://tokio.rs/docs/getting-started/hello-world/) to get a better understanding of how to write asynchronous code in rust.

Comment: It looks like I cannot call `tokio::run` from a `hyper` service, it fails with `attempted to run an executor while another executor is already running`.

Comment: Try `hyper::rt::spawn` instead of `tokio::run`. `hyper` initializes its own executor, but `tokio::run` attempts to initialize a new one which is why you're seeing the error message. `spawn` will run a future on an existing executor.

Comment: `hyper::rt::spawn` is probably the right way. Also, I've realized my mistake, which the code sample I posted completely misses. I will update it to make it clearer

Answer (score 0):

There were quite a few mistakes in my understanding of how `hyper` works. Basically:

- if a service should handle futures, do not use `service_fn_ok` to create it (it is meant for synchronous services): use `service_fn`;
- do not use `wait`: all futures use the same executor, the execution will just hang forever (there is a warning in the docs but oh well...);
- as ecstaticm0rse notices, `hyper::rt::spawn` could be used to read stats asynchronously, instead of doing it in the service

> Is tokio somehow required by shiplift?

Yes. It uses `hyper`, which throws `executor failed to spawn task` if the default `tokio` executor is not available (working with futures nearly always requires an executor anyway).

Here is a minimal version of what I ended up with (tokio 0.1.20 and hyper 0.12):

```
use std::net::SocketAddr;
use std::time::{Duration, Instant};

use tokio::prelude::*;
use tokio::timer::Interval;

use hyper::{
    Body, Response, service::service_fn_ok,
    Server, rt::{spawn, run}
};

fn init_background_task(swarm_name: String) -> impl Future<Item = (), Error = ()> {
    Interval::new(Instant::now(), Duration::from_secs(1))
        .map_err(|e| panic!(e))
        .for_each(move |_instant| {
            futures::future::ok(())  // unimplemented: call shiplift here
        })
}

fn init_server(address: SocketAddr) -> impl Future<Item = (), Error = ()> {
    let service = move || {
        service_fn_ok(|_request| Response::new(Body::from("unimplemented")))
    };
    Server::bind(&address)
        .serve(service)
        .map_err(|e| panic!("Server error: {}", e))
}


fn main() {
    let background_task = init_background_task("swarm_name".to_string());
    let server = init_server(([127, 0, 0, 1], 9898).into());

    run(hyper::rt::lazy(move || {
        spawn(background_task);
        spawn(server);
        Ok(())
    }));
}
```